How do I stack columns with the same header as one column in Excel?
I have an Excel spreadsheet that is formatted like this (with 200 columns):
What i have right now:

How do I format it like this?
What i am trying to get:

I'm very new to this, and I've been stuck trying to merge the columns for a while. The solution posted here works partially, but only adds the first cell in each column to the newly created column.
how do I merge columns with the same header name by adding the data as a new row for that column?

Not a free-scripting site. Please show what you have tried on your own! Also if you research more could have resolved it before asking. There are ample of solution posted! Should have shown the debugging details!

@MayukhBhattacharya Are you aware that you have closed this question as a duplicate using the same question OP linked to as what he tried and what didn't work for him? And it doesn't, right?

@VBasic2008 Sir, he has tried nothing, if he would, then could have resolved it. There is no debugging details clearly asking to write the whole formula from scratch. The link in which P.b sir has the accepted solution could have been modified. Nevermind, although OP has got three solutions here!

Stack Same-Named Columns (Vertically)
=LET(list,A1:F4,
    h,TAKE(list,1),
    d,DROP(list,1),
    hu,UNIQUE(h,1),
    dn,IFS(d<>"",d),
    VSTACK(hu,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",hu,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        HSTACK(rr,TOCOL(IFS(h=r,dn),2,1)))),,1),"")))


Ignores blanks, cells containing Nothing, and cells with errors.
The cell that shows Nothing contains the formula ="" but is formatted as @"Nothing".


EDIT

Replaced XMATCH(h,r) with h=r in the formula above suggested by nkalvi.
In the following more sophisticated solution, the following options are available:

You can choose to show headers or not with show_header.
You can show columns without a 'match' or not with show_header_ifna only when show_header is 1.
If there is no match, you can choose what to display with if_not_available only when show_header_ifna is 0.



=LET(list,A1:F4,show_header,1,show_header_ifna,1,
        if_not_available,NA(),
    h,TAKE(list,1),
    hu,UNIQUE(h,1),
    d,DROP(list,1),
    dn,IFS(d<>"",d),
    c,REDUCE("",hu,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        c,TOCOL(IFS(h=r,dn),2,1),
        ce,ISERR(TAKE(c,1)),
        IF(show_header,IF(ce,IF(show_header_ifna,HSTACK(rr,r),rr),
                HSTACK(rr,VSTACK(r,c))),
            IF(ce,rr,HSTACK(rr,c)))))),
    IF(COLUMNS(c)=1,if_not_available,IFNA(DROP(c,,1),"")))


The most interesting (time-consuming) detail for me was that I used ce,ISERR(c), which didn't work because it returns an array if TOCOL doesn't error out. ce,ISERR(TAKE(c,1)), fixed it since TOCOL(...,2) will produce either an array with no errors or a #CALC! error as a single value.


Nice! IFS(h = r would work too, right?

Of course, you're right (how embarrassing). I fixed it. I'll spare you the details of how this happened. Thanks for taking an interest.

I like your approach and learn a lot from your answers!

Similar to the post you referenced, you first need UNIQUE to get the header:
In cell A7: =UNIQUE(A1:F1,TRUE,FALSE)
Then in cell A8: =TOCOL(FILTER($A$2:$F$4,$A$1:$F$1=A7),1,TRUE)
FILTER($A$2:$F$4,$A$1:$F$1=A7) FILTERS out data for header 1
TOCOL(FILTER()) reshape the data into a single column.
Then you can drag the formula in A8 to the right.

If you want everything in one formula, you will need REDUCE and LAMBDA as in your referenced post:
=LET(
    header, A1:F1,
    data, A2:F4,
    unique_header, UNIQUE(header, TRUE, FALSE),
    res, REDUCE(
        "",
        unique_header,
        LAMBDA(stacked, x,
            LET(filtered, TOCOL(FILTER(data, header = x), 1, TRUE), HSTACK(stacked, VSTACK(x, filtered)))
        )
    ),
    IFERROR(DROP(res, 0, 1), "")
)


Same formula should work of that linked article. Just use FILTER() instead of IFS() function. Because, IFS() will return 0 for blank cells while FILTER() will return empty string and TOCOL() will ignore those empty string.
=LET(u,UNIQUE(B2:G2,1),VSTACK(u,DROP(REDUCE(0,TOROW(u),LAMBDA(a,b,IFNA(HSTACK(a,TOCOL(FILTER(B3:G5,B2:G2=b),3,TRUE)),""))),,1)))



Better use TOCOL(data, 3, TRUE). because based on the OP's screenshot, I think they want data to be "scanned by column".

=LET(u,UNIQUE(B2:G2,1),VSTACK(u,DROP(REDUCE(0,u,LAMBDA(a,b,IFNA(HSTACK(a,TOCOL(FILTER(B3:G5,B2:G2=b),3)),""))),,1)))
